# regex to split string into parts

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a string that has the following value,

```
ID Number / 1234
Name: John Doe Smith
Nationality: US
```

The string will always come with the *Name:* pre appended.

My regex expression to get the fullname is `(?<=Name:\s)(.*)` works fine to get the whole name. This `(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)` seems to get the first name.

So an expression each to get for first,middle & last name would be ideal. Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: You are using a positive lookbehind, so you can omit the group. Then just split the full match on a space.

Comment: am new to regex. The idea is to split the name and assign to variables accordingly. So an expression each for first name, middle & last name would be ideal. Like this *(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)* seems to get the first name

Comment: Assuming your middle names can actually be multiple middle names, try: [`^Name: (\S+)(?: (\S+(?: \S+)*))? (\S+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/GLgHSv/1). Note, names are generally a bit hard to catch.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, In case you have not seen the edit to the original question I would like to get each name part using one regex expression for each. So one expression that will get middle name and another that will get just the last name, (assuming all are one word)

Comment: What particular regex flavour are you looking for? Which app are you using? Why do you need three seperate regexes? Can't you use variables?

Comment: The thing with names is that there can be multiple "words". The only thing you know currently is that there should be at least a word after `Name:`  What about `Madonna`?

Comment: @JvdV The regex flavour is .net. The answer for the other two would take this beyond the scope of the regex but it has something to do with data upload automation. And yes I will be using variables at some point.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the names will always come in three parts so that does not worry me. I would like to know if it is in fact possible to get middle/last name using regex for each, assuming there is a single space between each. Thank you

Comment: @Ayubx Sure, you can use the posted answer of Maroun, and get the values from capture group 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I did have a look at the answer of Maroun but i can only use regex expressions. His solution has python by the looks of it. Can you illustrate the regex expression to get the middle name ? This gets the first name *(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)*

Comment: hmmmm no @JvdV those do not seem to work. There is a *Name:* that will always be part of the name if you will, so i do not think you have considered that but thank you

Comment: @JvdV The data for full name will always be *Name: John Doe Smith* and not John Doe Smith. Now this needs to be split into three using an expression for each, keeping in mind that *Name:* will always be part of the name. hope that makes sense.

Comment: So why does [`\S+(?=(?:\s\S+){2}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cJdLIx/1/) not work? Or [`\S+(?=\s\S+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Uvo8bA/1) or [`\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/k6TuDu/1)

Comment: @JvdV its not working on regextester[dot]com :S but I can see it is working on regex101. Many thanks

Comment: You can use [`http://regexstorm.net/tester`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cS%2b%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5cs%5cS%2b%29%7b2%7d%24%29&i=Name%3a+John+Doe+Smith) as a `.Net` regex tester. You'll see it works over there too.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks again but there was a reason I was using the *Name:* to identify the name. That is because in the data there are other data parts like id & nationality. As the *Name:* is preappended to the name I have to use *Name:* in the regex expression to identify the name, which the expression i put in the question already does. Your solution will work if the data is only the name. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: In .net you can use `(?<=\bName:\s*)\w+(?: \w+){2}`  see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbName%3a%5cs*%29%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a+%5cw%2b%29%7b2%7d&i=ID+Number+%2f+1234%0d%0aName%3a+John+Doe+Smith%0d%0aNationality%3a+US&o=m) or to get just the middle name `(?<=\bName:\s*\w+\s+)\w+` You could also use a quantifier to select the nth word to match `(?<=\bName:(?:\s+\w+){2}\s+)\w+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Brilliant! Looks like this works. Thank you so much. You could put this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the comments that you use .NET you can make use of a quantifier in the lookbehind to select which part of a "word" you want to select after `Name:`

For example, to get the 3rd part of the name, you can use `{2}` as the quantifier.

To match non whitespace chars instead of word characters only, you can use `\S+` instead of `\w+`

```
(?<=\bName:(?:\s+\w+){2}\s+)\w+
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that from the current position directly to the left is:

  - `\bName:` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, match `Name:`
  - `(?:\s+\w+){2}` Repeat 2 times as a whole, matching 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars. (To get the second name, use `{1}` or omit the quantifier, to get the first name use `{0}`)
  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbName%3a%28%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%29%7b2%7d%5cs%2b%29%5cw%2b&i=ID+Number+%2f+1234%0d%0aName%3a+John+Doe+Smith%0d%0aNationality%3a+US&o=m)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture those into 3 different groups:

```py
(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)
```

```py
>>> re.search('(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)', 'Name: John Doe Smith').groups()
('John', 'Doe', 'Smith')
```

Or, once you got the full name, you can apply `split` on the result, and get the names on a list:

```py
>>> re.split(r'\s+', 'John Doe Smith')
['John', 'Doe', 'Smith']
```

For some reason I assumed Python, but the above can be applied to almost any programming language.

Comment: If you're restricted to technology without the abilities above, please let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I can only use regex expressions. The idea is to split the name and assign to variables accordingly. I tried your solution and not sure how would i go if i wanted to get the split one at a time. So an expression each for first name, middle & last name would be ideal.  *(?<=Name:\s)([a-zA-Z]+)* seems to get the first name